# Sum TD in TABLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>One</td><td>123</td><td></td><td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td><td>52</td><td></td><td>53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three</td><td>234</td><td></td><td>56</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('#tab').click(function(){
   sum();
})

function sum(){
 //????
}
```

How is the best method for sum column from second and fourth TD and fill in to third TD for each TR?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/bYf8C/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sum(){
    $("tr").each(function(){
        var sum = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()) + 
                  parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text());
        $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text(sum);
    })
}
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYf8C/10/

Answer (score 2):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bYf8C/2/

```
$('#tab').click(function(){
   sum();
})

function sum(){
    $('#tab').find('tr').each(function(){
        var first = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text(),
            second = $(this).children('td:eq(3)').text();

        $(this).children('td:eq(2)').html(function(){
          return parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
        });
    });
}
```

As Bojangles suggested in the comments, `children()` is faster than `find()`, and `:eq` is faster than `:nth-child`. My edit reflects that.

Comment: This is quite inefficient code, although it _does_ work. Consider caching the table cells in a variable, as well as using `.eq()` instead of the slower `:nth-child()` selector. Using `.children()` instead of `.find()` would make it faster, too

Comment: @Bojangles - The table is 3 rows long.

Comment: That's just an example the OP gave. What if the table is 100 rows long and is recalculated on a keyup event, for example? [A quick test](http://jsperf.com/magic-beans) shows clearly that a few quick optimisations both clean up the code, and speeds it up massively (by 73%)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
$(function() {
  $('#tab').on('click', function sum() {
    $('tr', this).each(function(index, tr) {
      var td1, td3;
      td1 = parseInt(tr.children[1].textContent, 10);
      td3 = parseInt(tr.children[3].textContent, 10);
      tr.children[2].innerHTML = td1 + td3;
    });
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uvuzeq/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(){
   $('#tab tr').each(function() {
      var number1 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(1).html()); 
      var number2 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(3).html());
      $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(number1 + number2)
   });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYf8C/11/